# How to connect docker container via ssh?

Tags: ssh, docker, boot2docker

I use the tutorial in this：
https://docs.docker.com/examples/running_ssh_service/
and I have finish above step, and I use the docker ps to find the port ,and assume my port is 32769 when I input this command:

> ssh root@192.168.1.2 -p 32769

it just show me :

> ssh root@localhost -p 32769 ssh: connect to host localhost port 32769:
>   Connection refused

this is information about command that "docker ps":

```
bash-3.2$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
5e22e16a7742        liuxin/centos:ssh   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb   40 minutes ago      Up 40 minutes       0.0.0.0:32769->22/tcp    c_ssh_centos        
eaa412773bb2        registry            "docker-registry"      2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   registry
```

I use the Mac OS X and have opened remote login.
I don't know how to make connect successed.
Thanks

Comment: can you post `docker port 5e2` see the doc http://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/port/  In fact I had not noticed this information was available in your post, forget it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ssh is telling you that it's trying to connect to `localhost`, then that's your problem. Docker doesn't run natively on the Mac. Instead, it runs in a VM which has its own IP address and *that's* what you need to connect to.

Assuming you're using `docker-machine`, you can do this:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER         STATE     URL                          SWARM
dev    *        vmwarefusion   Running   tcp://192.168.201.162:2376
```

That shows that I have an active VM named "dev" as my Docker machine. Then I can run

```
ssh root@$(docker-machine ip dev) -p 32769
```

To ssh to the appropriate IP address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I using docker-machine,it just show me "command not found". I use boot2docker, What should I do in this case?

Comment: I using "boot2docker ip",then it show me "192.168.59.103".It work.Thanks.